# client server socket structured message c#

Tags: c#, sockets, server, client

Helllo guys,
I'm creating client-server game using sockets. I'm trying to use structured messages, then serialize and deserialize them, there is 3 strings in my structure. My code serializes first string, but mess up two following ones. I been told that my structure might have enough space space only for one string.

My message structure:

```
public struct Message_PDU
{
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 10101)]
    public string commandID;
    public string playerIndex;
    public string score;
};
```

Serialize method

```
     private byte[] Serialize(Object myObject)
    {
        int size = Marshal.SizeOf(myObject);
        IntPtr ip = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(size); //allocate unmanaged memory equivelent to the size of the object
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(myObject, ip, false); //marshal the object into the allocated memory
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[size];
        Marshal.Copy(ip, byteArray, 0, size); //place the contents of memory into a byte[]
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ip); //free unmanaged memory
        return byteArray;
    }
```

Sending message code:

```
            String szdata1 = "--";
            String szdata2 = AlliasText.Text;
            String szdata3 = "1";



            Message_PDU myPDU = new Message_PDU();
            myPDU.commandID = szdata1;
            myPDU.playerIndex = szdata2;
            myPDU.score = szdata3;
            byte[] byData = Serialize(myPDU); //convert structure into a byte[]
            m_ClientSocket.Send(byData, SocketFlags.None);
```

I tried to increase SizeConst, but it didn't work. Debugging shows that only first string gets serialized.
 Thank you

Comment: The MarshalAs attribute is only applied to the first string. You should also be using StructLayout sequential.

Comment: Why is everything strings? I feel like all of those should be some kind of integer type.

Comment: `Marshal` is a pretty brittle way to deal with serialization - I don't recommend it - but: you say "it didn't work" - what *happened*? what did you see?

Comment: Ron, thanks for comment. I'm using StructLayout, but I didn't include the line in my post.

Comment: I believe it can be strings or integers, because it gets converted into bytes anyway. @MarcGravell The error message I receive while deserialise is: System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt. But when I debug I can see my "--" string in hexadecimal, but the rest becomes random values.

Comment: using `SizeConst` with string data is just a terrible idea; if you're trying to send data by sockets, this is frankly just not a good approach. Are you open to changing it? tools like protobuf-net would make this *embarrassingly trivial* - or you could just use BinaryWriter/BinaryReader if you want to roll a basic custom protocol

Comment: Marc : There is nothing wrong with sending strings.  You have the same issue sending either binary or strings.  When you send a message the receiver needs to know where the end of the message is going to be.  So use one of following 1) Ascii : Add a terminating character at end of message that is not part of message 2) Ascii or Binary : Add a byte count to beginning of message 3) Ascii or Binary : Use fixed length messages.

Answer (score 0):

thank for trying to help. My course leader helped me to sort it out.
Basically, I marshalized only first string instead of each one of them, because I thought that I am marshalizing whole structure.

Message structure should look like this:

```
public struct Message_PDU
{
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
public string commandID;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
public string playerIndex;
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 101)]
public string score;
};
```

Also, SizeConst is just charachters length sent in the message, and it's important to make as short as possible.
Thank you again, I hope it helps someone in the future.